# How can a Tableau Server user change the axis view on a granular table?

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a capacity dashboard that has a granular aspect with multiple rows on the axis. The purpose is so that the user can see the specific view as the fields get more specific, such as Region to Market to Territory. My main problem is if there is a way for a user on Tableau Server to be able to edit the axis (maybe through a filter) so they could basically scale back the granularity a little bit. I know that in Tableau Desktop, you can just remove the dimensions, but I am hoping there is away to do that as a user in Server. Here are some pictures of my
workbook for examples:
[image]
[image]

You can see that when Territory is removed, it get less specific and shows all of Canada as a whole, grouped together. I am hoping there is a filter view or some way a user could change this dynamically. I have created a parameter with strings that matches the row dimensions that maybe when selected, will show up to that row, but I am not sure how to link that into the dashboard. Here is a picture of that:

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a Parameter with your three Axis choices.  It should look like this:

[image: Parameter]

Next, create a calculated field that only references the Parameter like this:

[image: Calculation]

Next, you will create three separate sheets.  On each one, add the Axis Filter to the Filters Shelf.  One each separate page, select one of the three values in your Parameter.  (Tip - if the value doesn't show up you can either change the parameter or type it in manually under "Custom value list".)

[image: Filter]

What this does is create a filter whereby only ONE of the sheets will show up at any time.  Meaning if you want to work on the Market sheet select the Market value in the Parameter.

Finally, to bring it all together, you will put these on a dashboard.  Create a new Dashboard and add a Horizontal (or Vertical, it doesn't matter) Object (aka layout container) onto the dashboard.  Put all three Sheets *inside* the layout container.  You will see only one will be displayed but all three will have headers.  On each sheet, click on the header and check "Hide Title" like this:

[image: Dashboard]

Finally, click on any downward triangle and show the parameter:

[image: Show Parameter]

Now, by changing the parameter your user is selecting from three different sheets... effectively letting them change the Axis.

You can also view this documentation on the [Tableau Help site](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dashboards_sheet_selector.htm).

Comment: Ah thank you! I was trying the parameter route but couldn't find a way to link it like that. That is very useful for future dynamic uses. Thank you very much.